# Select Start date that is 60 business days old

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need the ability to select a start date that is 60business days prior to the current date.  I have a calendar built with dates and business dates, etc.  My current (and unsuccessful) method is below:

```
DECLARE @Mode int
SET     @Mode = 0

SET     @StartDate = CASE WHEN @Mode = 0
                      THEN (SELECT BusDate FROM Leads.dbo.Calendar 
                            WHERE Date = DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF (DAY,0,GETDATE())-60,0))
                      WHEN @Mode = 1
                      THEN DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF (mm,0,GETDATE())-2,0)
                      END
```

This method goes back 60 calendar days, not 60 business days.  I'm having a challenge with getting this down to Business days.  Disregard the Mode = 1 portion (this calculates by month).
Any help would be appreciated.

```
The Calendar table has the following fields:
SELECT [Date]
  ,[MMDDYYYY]
  ,[Year]
  ,[QTR]
  ,[Month]
  ,[Week]
  ,[YTDDay]
  ,[QTDDay]
  ,[MTDDay]
  ,[WeekDayNbr]
  ,[Quarter]
  ,[MonthLName]
  ,[MonthName]
  ,[DayOfWeekS]
  ,[DayOfWeek]
  ,[KindOfDay]
  ,[Description]
  ,[Period]
  ,[YrMo]
  ,[YrWk]
  ,[StartDate]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[BusPeriod]
  ,[Holiday]
  ,[NonBus]
  ,[BusDaysInMonth]
  ,[BusDay]
  ,[BusDaysRemain]
  ,[BusDate]
  ,[YYYYMMDD]
```

BusDay is the business day for a month (1, 2, 3, etc).  There currently is no column that says 1 for yes and 0 for No to indicate it is a business day, although I could add that.  The NonBus and Holiday fields operate that way: 1 is Holiday or Non-business day (holidays and weekends) and 0 is not.

Comment: You need a calendar table. Here is one article that explains this type of thing. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/70482/

Comment: do you need to exclude holidays or only weekends?

Comment: please provide schema and data from `calendar` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know much about your calendar table but you could do something like this. Use a derived table that only consists of business days that are less than today's date and give each a row number ordered by date desc. Then select the date from 60th row.

```
select busdate
from 
    (
        select *,
        row_number() over (order by date desc) as dayNo
        from leads.dbo.calendar
        where nonBus = 0 -- Only business days
        and date < cast(getdate() as date)
    ) busDays
where dayno = 60
```

Comment: I could probably use this and change the WHERE clause to Nonbus = 0, which would effectively give me Business days (although I think it would help to add the Busday column at some point).  I'll try to implement this.

Comment: @MikeMarshall I was using column names just to give you an idea since we don't know how your calendar table is setup. The logic should work. I tested it on my own database and calendar table.